# Moving a part of a function into another function

Tags: c++

Here's a structure declaration for the nodes of a circular list:

```
struct  Node
{
    int x; // info field
    struct Node *Next;
};
```

In `int main()` I have a loop that fills the list with numbers from 1 to 10:

```
int main()
{

    Node *Head=NULL, *Tail=NULL; 
    int size = 0; 
    int info = 0; 

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
    { // for
        info++;
        size++; 
        Node *temp=new Node; 
        temp->Next=Head; 
        temp->x=info; 

        if (Head!=NULL)
        {
            Tail->Next = temp; 
            Tail=temp; 
        }

        else Head=Tail=temp;
    } // endfor
}
```

How to make a function that contains this loop and is called from `main()`?
Something like this:

```
void Fill(struct Node *Head, struct Node *Tail, int &x, int &info)
{
  // <function body>
}

int main()
{
...
Fill(Head, Tail, x, info);
...
}
```

doesn't work :(

Comment: What to you mean by "How to make a function that contains this cycle"? And what exactly does not work? There is nothing in your function's body. What are `x` and `info` supposed to hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needs the power to actually modify `Head` and `Tail` (i.e. modify where these pointers point). Therefore, you need to pass them by reference `Node *&`.

On the other hand, `x` is not a variable you need to pass to the function. (It's a member of the `Node` struct.)

So your function should be defined like this:

```
void Fill(Node *&Head, Node *&Tail, int &info)
{
   // <function body>
}
```

Anything you want to pass into the function such that any changes the function makes to it are reflected outside the function, you need to pass by reference (or do something even more complicated, like pointers, which in the case of `Head` and `Tail` would mean pointers to pointers).

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't know about `*&`. Yes, I've made a mistake, it's `info` and `size` variables I need to pass to the function, not `x`.

Comment: @WildSpirit Yes, I wasn't sure about `size`. If you want to modify that inside the function as well (and have the modification reflected outside the function), then yes, you need to pass that as reference as well.